# Segmentation fault when call an static library function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, static-libraries

I have simple OpenGL C program (from [NeHe lesson 2](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=02)). There is initialization function InitGL.
And i have function `foo` in my static library:

```
void foo(double *p)
{
    p[0] = 1.0;
}
```

When i define array of double at start of `InitGL`:

```
double arr[1000];
```

and modify it in `InitGL` all works fine.

When i allocate memory for this array dynamically and call `foo` from `InitGL` all works fine too:

```
double *p = (double *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
foo(p);
```

But when i define array at start of `InitGL` and call `foo` from `InitGL`:

```
double p[1000];
foo(p);
```

i get segmentation fault at line

```
p[0] = 1.0;
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Show us the actual code -- without it, we're just guessing.

Comment: The presented code should work fine. I'd blame memory corruption from another part of your code, as it only occurs when put on stack.

Comment: Big sorry, i founded mistake and updated my question :)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, then accept it, so this does not show as an unanswered question.

Comment: @Software, I just edited the question and posted their "answer" as a wiki answer, which seems reasonable in the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silver_Ghost's edited question, entered here so the question doesn't show up as having 0 answers:

> Very very stupid mistake :D
>   Initially i've writen a function:
>
> ```
> void cg_random_points(double **dest, int n, 
>           double xl, double xr,
>           double yl, double yr,
>           double zl, double zr) for generate set of random points in
> ```
>
> 3D space. Of course there was
>   segmentation fault because i must
>   declare number of columns (i read it
>   30 minutes ago in Kernighan and
>   Ritchie book :)   When i fix function
>   declaration to
>
> ```
> void cg_random_points(double (*dest)[3], int n, 
>           double xl, double xr,
>           double yl, double yr,
>           double zl, double zr) segmetation fault continued throw by
> ```
>
> one for-loop where i forgot change
>   10000 to 1000.   Now all works fine.